# aspnet mvc not arrivable request form data

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, web, backend

I am building a website in ASPNET MVC architecture. When posting the data on the html form, it gives an error while sending the data to the background in the controller part.

```
<form ..... >
    <div class="form-group" style="width:50%">
         <input type="text" name="data1" class="form-control" value="" style="background:lightgray" placeholder="example write.." id="data1" required>
         <input type="text" name="data2" class="form-control" value="" id="data2">
         <input type="text" name="data3" class="form-control" value="" id="data3">
    </div>
</form>
```

Don't get hung up on the names, I've changed them to share on stackoverflow.

It happens when I change the id and name fields in the html form, but this will lead to having to change more than one field in several places.

```
string data1 = Request.Form["data1"].ToString();
string data2 = Request.Form["data2"].ToString();
string data3 = Request.Form["data3"].ToString().ToUpper();
string data4 = Request.Form["data4"].ToString();
string data5 = Request.Form["data5"].ToString();
string data6 = Request.Form["data6"].ToString();
```

Has anyone come across such a silly problem?

Error text: **System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at**

I'm watching with F10, data comes in another request form

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FScqV.png)

Try-catch does not come in another field

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36Qhh.png)

Comment: What stops you using strongly typed model?  Would make your life easier with the form HTML and posting back.

Comment: I've looked on the web now, but it actually uses viewdata. The event you say?

Comment: See [this](https://www.completecsharptutorial.com/asp-net-mvc5/4-ways-to-create-form-in-asp-net-mvc.php)

Comment: my goal is not to show data as a list. I will check with this data in the database and with a few queries. I feel like it's better when listing the method you mentioned (just thought). Isn't the viewbag kept in the whole project whereas these variables will only take up space in that post

Comment: No Viewbag is just a way of transfering data to the frontend form.  Model is pretty much same in terms of data transfer, just a easier/nicer way of doing it because the framework will take care of data binding like numbers/strings etc Really suggest reading some basic mvc tutorials as there are lots online.